# iOS: Height of iAd banner view for universal app?

Tags: ios, iad, banner

I want to make my app universal with one storyboard for all devices. I have now a view below my table view which should contain the iAd banner, unless the user has made the in app purchase to remove the ads. So now I want to place the iAd banner within this view, but I don't know how big this view must be? Very confused about all the information in the internet, since a lot of stuff has been deprecated with the universal storyboards...

Answer (score 0):

Apple's own iAD Programming Guide does not cover the Adaptive Layout with Size Classes the last I checked.  So, you may want to try and turn off Size Classes for your StoryBoard and use 2 StoryBoards.  But, this will make defining Constraints more important to adjust for various device sizes.

iAd Programming Guide (check the Banner View Concepts section)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html